# Checking Whether Class Var Happens

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

So i'm trying to make this simple multiple choice quiz and i want to make it object oriented. I've created the class in which a question can be modeled around but i want when the first question is answered
 i wan the second question to start but i have tried a class var changes but nothing works

My Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

class Window:
    def __init__(self, root, canvas, question, a, b, c, correct):
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.question = question
        self.answerA = a
        self.answerB = b
        self.answerC = c
        self.answer = correct
        self.final = False

        if self.answer == 1:
            self.canvas.tag_bind('A', '<Button 1>', self.correct)
            self.canvas.tag_bind('B', '<Button 1>', self.wrong)
            self.canvas.tag_bind('C', '<Button 1>', self.wrong)
        elif self.answer == 2:
            self.canvas.tag_bind('A', '<Button 1>', self.wrong)
            self.canvas.tag_bind('B', '<Button 1>', self.correct)
            self.canvas.tag_bind('C', '<Button 1>', self.wrong)
        elif self.answer == 3:
            self.canvas.tag_bind('A', '<Button 1>', self.wrong)
            self.canvas.tag_bind('B', '<Button 1>', self.wrong)
            self.canvas.tag_bind('C', '<Button 1>', self.correct)

        self.canvas.tag_bind('Again', '<Button 1>', self.redirect)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('Correct', '<Button 1>', self.redirect)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        self.canvas.create_text(250, 125, text=self.question, font=('Helvetica', 20))

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 250, 150, 300, fill='Black', activefill='Orange', tags='A')
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(225, 250, 275, 300, fill='Black', activefill='Orange', tags='B')
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(350, 250, 400, 300, fill='Black', activefill='Orange', tags='C')

        self.canvas.create_text(125, 350, text=self.answerA, font=('Helvetica', 15), width=100)
        self.canvas.create_text(250, 350, text=self.answerB, font=('Helvetica', 15), width=100)
        self.canvas.create_text(375, 350, text=self.answerC, font=('Helvetica', 15), width=100)

    def correct(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        self.canvas.create_text(250, 125, text='Correct', font=('Helvetica', 20))

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(125, 250, 375, 400, fill='Black', activefill='Orange', tags='Correct')
        self.right = True
        self.wrongg = False

    def wrong(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        self.canvas.create_text(250, 125, text='Wrong', font=('Helvetica', 20))

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(125, 250, 375, 400, fill='Black', activefill='Orange', tags='Again')
        self.wrongg = True
        self.right = False

    def redirect(self, event):
        print('Redirecting...')
        if self.wrongg == True:
            print('Drawing...')
            self.draw()
        elif self.correct == True:
            self.final = True

questionOne = Window(root, canvas, 'test', 'a', 'b', 'c', 3)
questionOne.draw()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it means: "Nothing works"? Do you receive an error message? Does something work? Have you tried unit testing? So, did you try to test the code step-by-step?

Comment: @Alex_P By nothing works i mean ive tried different methods like returning values from the class then doing an if statement but even though the values change in the class the if statement doesnt work beacuse theres no loop, this could work but i dont know if theres a better way about it. Thats why theres a self.final so if you get it correct it will be true if its true then go to next question